# ASC DESC in the same link

Tags: php, html, sql

```
if (isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] == 'category')
{

    $sql .= " ORDER BY category ".$_GET["direction"];
}

<a href='?order=category&direction=ASC'>
```

When the user clicks second time on the link I want to order the table in DESC order. I have the a-z order I need to reverse them when the user clicks on the same link.

Comment: So are you asking how to change the anchor tag querystring?

Comment: Pass `DESC` instead of `ASC` when user already clicked the link

Comment: You should read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) as your code is vulnerable.

Comment: Guys, feel free to upvote the answer if you think it is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check what is contained in the `$_GET['direction']` and reverse it each time the submit is run.

Also, to take care of page reloads, save the value of previous direction in session.

```
$dir = 'DESC'; // set default for first execution
@session_start(); // start the session if it isn't already started.
if(!empty($_GET['direction'])){
  $dir = $_GET['direction'] == 'ASC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'; // avoids SQL injection.
  $_SESSION['direction'] = $dir;
}elseif(!empty($_SESSION['direction'])){
  $dir = $_SESSION['direction'];
 }
if (isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] == 'category') {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY category ".$dir;
}

$reverseDir= $dir =='DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'; //reverses the direction to be used in the link
<a href='?order=category&direction='<?php echo $reverseDir;?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the status of click in session/cookies.

```
if (isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] == 'category') {
  $sql .= " ORDER BY category ".$_GET["direction"];
  $dir = $_GET['direction'] == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
 }
 if($_SESSION['click'] == 0){
    echo "<a href='?order=category&direction=ASC'>";
 } else{ 
    echo "<a href='?order=category&direction=DESC'>";
 }
```

Comment: I am guessing you will get a Undefined index from this

Comment: No, you have to set session['click'] = 1 or o  in the redirect page.

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['click'])){
 $_SESSION['click'] = 0;  // change it according to condition
} else{
  // for the first time
 $_SESSION['click'] = 0;
}

Comment: Would be more useful to put that in your answer as then people could read it